# Multiprocessing doing Many Fast Calculations

Tags: python, pandas, namespaces, multiprocessing

I have an interesting multi-processing problem with structure that I might be able to exploit.  The problem involves a largish ~80 column `DataFrame` (`df`) in Pandas with many columns and a function `func` that operates on *pairs* (~80*79/2 pairs) of those columns in `df` and takes a fairly short amount of time on each run.

the code looks like

```
mgr = Manager()
ns = mgr.Namespace()
ns.df = df

pool = Pool(processes=16)
args = [(ns, list(combo)) for combo in list(combinations(df.columns, 2))]
results = pool.map(func, args)
pool.close()
```

The above is not fast but faster than without the pool but only faster by a factor of 7 or so. I'm worried that the the overhead from so many calls is the issue.  Is there a good way to exploit the structure here for MultiProcessing?

Comment: pool.join() does nothing in this script pool.map already returns a list in the order of the arguments and pool.close() already closed the pool you are trying to join.

Answer (score 0):

That is a fairly standard result. Nothing will scale perfectly linearly when run in parallel because of the overhead required to set up each process and pass data between processes. Keep in mind that `(80 * 79) / 2 = 3,160` is actually a very small number assuming the function is not extremely computationally intensive (i.e. takes a really long time). All else equal, the faster the function the greater the overhead cost to using multiprocessing because the time to set up an additional process is relatively fixed.

Overhead on multiprocessing mainly comes in memory if you have to make several duplications of a large dataset (one duplication for each process if the function is poorly designed) because processes do not share memory. Assuming your function is set up such that it can be easily parallelized, adding more processes is good so long as you do not exceed the number of processors on your computer. Most home computers do not have 16 processors (at most 8 is typical) and your result (that it is 7 times faster in parallel) is consistent with you having fewer than 16 processors. You can check the number of processors on your machine with `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`.

**EDIT:**

If you parallelize a function by passing the column string then it will repeatedly make copies of the dataframe. For example:

```
def StringPass(string1, string2):
    return df[string1] * df[string2]
```

If you parallelize StringPass it will copy the data frame at least once per process. In contrast:

```
def ColumnPass(column1, column2):
    return column1 * column2
```

If you pass just the necessary columns ColumnPass will only copy the columns necessary for each call to the function when run in parallel. So while `StringPass(string1, string2)` and `ColumnPass(df[string1], df[string2])` will return the same result, in multiprocessing the former will make several inefficient copies of the global `df`, while the latter will only copy the necessary columns for each call to the function.

Comment: So the CPU count is 16 actually.  The computer is fairly beefy.  Which is why I was concerned when the result came out to 7.  I was hoping the Manager would avoid the duplication of the DataFrame since it is all read only.  I'm just passing the string name for the columns so there should be little duplication there.

Comment: Can you post the function? You say you only pass it a string with a column name, but how is the function reading from the dataframe? My guess is that you just reference the dataframe within the function. This will not make a copy if you run it in the main process, but in multi-processing each individual process has its own memory and cannot access the memory of another process (including the main process). So even though you do not explicitly pass the dataframe to the function, it is at a minimum making 16 copies (one for each process).

Comment: Instead of referencing a column, I would rewrite the function to pass the actual column in question (or whatever data is actually necessary for the function to work). That way you only copy what you need to copy for any given process / call to the function.

Comment: I can't post the function unfortunately. My understanding was the reason to use a Manager was that I avoided making the copies of the df and that all the data is shared.  I'm I wrong?  Is it making 16 copies? 3,160 copies?  My goal with the Manager was to avoid passing the complicated column structure multiple times.